# FormBuilder always returns null for checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am creating a basic login page. All the user has to do if enter a password and then tick the box if they want to add another user. They will only be able to add another user if they have right permissions (this bit I will be able to figure out myself).

I have managed to get the password input working, where the user enters a password and I can log this to the console (please remember that this is just a test). I cannot seem to read the value of the checkbox, it always returns `null`.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="login">
  <h2 class="login-header">Log in</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="login-container" (ngSubmit)="login()">


    <p [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': isSubmitted && formControls.password.errors }">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autofocus  autocomplete="off">
    </p>

    <p>
      <input id="addUser" type="checkbox" name="addUser" value="addUser" formcontrolName="checkbox">Add User?
    </p>

    <div id="invalid">
      <p>Invalid Login... Try Again</p>
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private FormBuilder: FormBuilder, private httpService: HttpClient) { }

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  loginDetails: any = []
  loginLength: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      checkbox: new FormControl
    })
  }
  get formControls() { return this.loginForm.controls}

  login() {
    var checkboxresult = this.loginForm.get('checkbox').value;
    console.log(checkboxresult)
    console.log(this.loginForm)
  }
}
```

When the checkbox is checked I want it to return `true` and when it is not I want it to return `false`. Currently it only returns `null`.

I have tried following this [guide](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-radio-button-and-checkbox-example) but this returns `null`. How do I get `true` or `false` from the form when submit is pressed?

Comment: you have a typo in formControlName here ` <input id="addUser" type="checkbox" name="addUser" value="addUser" formcontrolName="checkbox">`..  It should be `formControlName`

Comment: @billyjov Good spot, this seems to haeve fixed issue. Thank you